# How to display the alert message in mvc controler

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert

I need to display the alert message in mvc controler(server side only not in client side). I have list of id in condition i need to display the all ids in my alert message.  I try below code:

```
  if (id.Count > 0)
            {
              // here i need to display the alert message with my ids 
            }
```

Comment: What alert message?  Where does it come from?

Comment: if it's for debugging purposes, use the debugger! Visual Studio has one of the best

Answer (score 0):

Nature of web applications won’t let you popup messages at the server side easily. But since you are in Visual Studio environment you can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to write messages to the output console ***(Ctrl+W, O).***

For more advanced scenarios you can implement your own diagnostics sub-framework by using System.Diagnostics as a base.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sure .. http://roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0133.html would be a good place to start. Please keep in mind, that you should use System.Diagnostics for projects that requires an advanced level of profiling/debugging only. While on the subject have a look at how to utilize the VS debugger as pointed by @Dogoku. You can do some pretty amazing things with the VS debugger out of the box